# getting id in context menu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have seen multiple posts regarding this but after all those solutions I stiil have this weird issue. 
I have implemented the following

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;

     Log.i(TAG,"onContextItemSelected id:"+String.valueOf(index));
```

}

I still get id as 0,1,2,.. and not the actual database row id. I am implementing list item click listener as well and here I get the correct row id based on the row. Is there something that I am missing.

Comment: you are using `info.position` so it will number return o,1,2....as expected ...

Comment: I m not about my ans so I m writing in comment..do somthing like this

Comment: I m not about my ans so I m writing in comment..do something like this View view = info.targetView .Now filter the type of view clicked using instanceOf like this if(view instanceOf imageview/button ) {int id =((ImageView)view).getID} .Now print the id Log.i(TAG,"onContextItemSelected id:"+String.valueOf(id));

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have a list view that you populated somehow. You get the position on an item in the list using the code you posted. From there, you should be able to get the actual item which hopefully includes the database ID.

It's hard to say how exactly you should do that without knowing how you populate your list.